# Getting extra equation numbers using align environment

Tags: numbering, align

so I'm having an issue with equation numbers and the align environment. This has happened with several of my equation blocks where there is an extra equation number in there for no reason that I can see. I've tried using \nonumber in several places but cannot seem to locate where the issue is coming from. My code is:

```
\begin{align}
    P(t) &= \frac{3}{2}\left[v_d(t)i_d(t)\right] \\
    Q(t) &= \frac{3}{2}\left[-v_d(t)i_q(t)\right] \\
\end{align}
```

and it looks like:

[image: Extra equation number]

Can anyone shed any light on this. I can split these into two separate equations instead of using align, but the thing is I have some really long equations that need to be split over multiple lines as well that I need a single equation number for. If someone could at least suggest a work around for me, I'd really appreciate it.

```
\begin{align}
P(t) &= \frac{\left(Re\left\{\overrightarrow{v}(t)\overrightarrow{i}(t)\right\} + Re\left\{\overrightarrow{v}(t)\overrightarrow{i}(t)^*\right\}\right)}{2} \nonumber \\
     &\qquad + \frac{\left(Re\left\{\overrightarrow{v}(t)\overrightarrow{i}(t)e^{-j\frac{4\pi}{3}}\right\} + Re\left\{\overrightarrow{v}(t)\overrightarrow{i}(t)^*\right\}\right)}{2} \\
     &\qquad + \frac{\left(Re\left\{\overrightarrow{v}(t)\overrightarrow{i}(t)e^{-j\frac{8\pi}{3}}\right\} + Re\left\{\overrightarrow{v}(t)\overrightarrow{i}(t)^*\right\}\right)}{2} \nonumber \\
\end{align}
```

[image: Same problem for multiline equation]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just omit the line-break directive at the end of the final equation in a given `align` group. E.g.,

```
\begin{align}
    P(t) &= \tfrac{3}{2}[v_d(t)i_d(t)] \\
    Q(t) &= \tfrac{3}{2}[-v_d(t)i_q(t)] % <- no "\\" directive
\end{align}
```

As the code shows, I would also (a) remove the `\left` and `\right` qualifiers as they actually don't do anything for the cases at hand and (b) replace `\frac` with `\tfrac`.

If you have a multi-line equation that should be assigned just one equation number, don't use an `align` environment. Instead, use a `split` environment inside an `equation` environment.

By the way, the arrows produced by `\overrightarrow` look disproportionately large; consider using `\vec` instead. For arrows (and other diacritics) set above the characters `i` and `j`, it's traditional to omit the "dot", i.e., to use a "dotless" `i` and `j`; this may be achieved in math mode by writing `\imath` and `\jmath`. Separately, I again would not use `\left` and `\right` to autosize the round parentheses and curly braces; consider using `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead. (By the way, the outermost round parentheses may be omitted in all three rows, right?)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example 
\setcounter{equation}{31}
\begin{align}
    P(t) &= \tfrac{3}{2}[v_d(t)i_d(t)] \\
    Q(t) &= \tfrac{3}{2}[-v_d(t)i_q(t)] 
\end{align}

\setcounter{equation}{20} % just for this example
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
P(t) 
&= \frac{
\Re\bigl\{\vec{v}(t)\vec{\imath}(t)\bigr\} + 
\Re\bigl\{\vec{v}(t)\vec{\imath}(t)^*\bigr\}}{2} \\
&\quad+ \frac{
\Re\bigl\{\vec{v}(t)\vec{\imath}(t)e^{-j\frac{4\pi}{3}}\bigr\} + 
\Re\bigl\{\vec{v}(t)\vec{\imath}(t)^*\bigr\}}{2} \\
&\quad+ \frac{
\Re\bigl\{\vec{v}(t)\vec{\imath}(t)e^{-j\frac{8\pi}{3}}\bigr\} + 
\Re\bigl\{\vec{v}(t)\vec{\imath}(t)^*\bigr\}}{2} 
\end{split}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For vectors, I'd recommend the less petty `\vv` from `esvect` instead: 8 arrow styles, and its size adjusts to the contents size.

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks for this suggestion. Having 8 arrow styles to choose from is definitely nifty. Just for the record: the size of the arrows produced by `\vec` also adjusts automatically to the applicable math style (viz., text/displaystyle, scriptstyle, and scriptscriptstyle).

Comment: I know, but it does not adapt to the length of the contents: compare `\vec{ABCD}` and `\vv{ABCD}`.

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks for providing this clarification. (I had thought the automatic size adjustment issue was about the math style in effect.)

Comment: @ico: This apckage doesn't seem to be well-known – probably because its main use is  for high-school geometry, but I find having the equivalent of \xrightarrow for vector arrows quite useful. The same author wrote an `esdiff` package that simplifies greatly (partial and non-partial) derivatives typing.