# Two equations with text inbetween, numbering problem

Tags: equations, numbering

**EDIT:**

Solved problem with just a `\\` too much at the very end.

**What do I want?**:

I am trying to write an equation with text tabbed to the right of the equation, then I want another small equation to the right of that text. Also I just want one numbering to all of this.

**I do not want to break up my align enviroment as I still want my alignment of my equations to be at the equal sign**

Picture of my problem, I only want that "(5)":

[image]

This is the interesting part of my code:

```
\begin{align}
    \intertext{Alltså:}
    %
    H(s) &= \frac{R+sL}{R+sL+s^2RLC},\tab  \text{där}\tab s=j\omega \label{eq:h_jw}\\
\end {align}
```

My whole align enviroment with the interesting code at the bottom:

```
\begin{align}
        Z_C &= \frac{1}{j\omega C};\ \ Z_L = j\omega L \\
        Z_1 &= \ddfrac{1}{\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{Z_L}} = \frac{RZ_L}{R+Z_L} \\
        %
        \intertext{Spänningsdelning enlig fig \# ger:}
        %
        \nonumber
        U_{ut} &= U_{in}\frac{Z_C}{Z_C+Z_1} \\
        %
        \nonumber
        \Rightarrow H(j\omega)&=\frac{U_{ut}}{U_{in}} = \frac{Z_C}{Z_C+Z_1} = \\
        %
        \intertext{Insättning av ekvation \# \& \# ger vidare:}
        %
        \nonumber
        &= \frac{Z_C}{Z_C+\frac{RZ_L}{R+Z_L}} = \frac{Z_C(R+Z_L)}{Z_CR+Z_CZ_L+Z_LR} = \\
        %
        \nonumber
        &= \ddfrac{\left[\frac{1}{j\omega C}(R+j\omega L)\right]}{\left[\frac{1}{j\omega C}R + \frac{1}{j\omega C}j\omega L + j\omega RL\right]} = \frac{R+j\omega L}{R+j\omega L + j^2\omega^2RLC} = \\[4pt]
        %
        \nonumber
        &= \Big[s = j\omega\Big] =  \frac{R+sL}{R+sL+s^2RLC}\\
        %
        \intertext{Alltså:}
        %
        H(s) &= \frac{R+sL}{R+sL+s^2RLC},\tab  \text{där}\tab s=j\omega \label{eq:h_jw}\\
    \end{align}
```

Comment: just delete the final `\\ `

Comment: please don't edit the solution into the question, it makes a mess of the archive, you can add an answer or I could

Comment: Removed it, sorry I don't really know how to use everything here.

Comment: What is `\ddfrac`?

Comment: @bernard It doesn't matter now. But it is a new command which makes some qoutients somewhat more visible. Sorry for not explaining that in the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments (OP incorporated the solution into the question)

Comment: @StefanPinnow: I was about to vote to close it too, but then I wondered whether it could turn out to be useful to other users as well.  Typing an extra \\ at the end of an `align` environment looks like something other people could do; yet, when I tried searching this site for “extra \\ in align” or “\\ at end of align”, I got zero results…

Comment: @StefanPinnow: I withdraw my previous comment and propose, instead, to mark this question as a duplicate of [Getting extra equation numbers using align environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327813/69818).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small error at the very end.
Just remove the `\\`.